# Salesforce: Cannot Modify Managed Component during upload new version

Tags: community, salesforcedx

We are suddenly facing an issue in our Salesforce Dev Org during uploading to create new version.
It has suddenly started to show the error that:

> **Cannot Modify Managed Component**
>
> The component you are attempting to modify is part of a managed
> package, and cannot be modified. For more information, see
> Insufficient Privileges Errors.

[image]

As you can see that error message is not clear. It did not give any hint about any file or some thing like that.
I tried everything. I even deployed very old commit and tried to upload but same error shows up.

We are stuck and can't find any solution online.
I would highly appreciate for any suggestion or help.

Thanks

Regards

Ayyaz

Comment: Your best bet is to get a Salesforce Support case logged so this can be investigated.

Comment: But do you think that we can get the Salesforce Support case logged for a Dev Org?

Comment: Yes if you are building managed package

Comment: @AyyazZafar When you look at the components included in your package before uploading do you see any red alert icon? What about the ability to delete next to one of the items in the list?